# Coding in React Native - "Unhandled JS Exception: ReferenceError"

Tags: ios, react-native, referenceerror

The title says everything. Does anybody have some experience with this type of error? I do not know what can i do to run the app on simulator.

[image: App simulation and the code]

Thank you

Comment: Oh, i have solved it right after i posted the question. For these who have problem that i have mensioned: instead of "require('react-native')" , you shall use 
"import React, { Component } from 'react' " and 
"import { View, Text, AppRegistry } from 'react-native' "
to fix it.